# PHP MySQL SUM Between Month

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use `BETWEEN` in my PHP - MySQL.

Example I have table :

```
badge_id | balance_type | balance_amount | balance_month
110702   | aa           | 250000         | January-2013
110702   | ab           | 100000         | January-2013
110702   | aa           | 100000         | February-2013
110702   | ab           | 90000          | February-2013
110702   | aa           | 100000         | March-2013
110702   | ab           | 110000         | March-2013
```

Now I want to `SUM` just for Balance Month from January-2013 until February-2013.

```
SELECT balance_type AS balance_type, SUM(balance_amount) AS value_sum
FROM t_balance 
WHERE badge_id = '110702' && balance_month BETWEEN 'August-2013' 
  and 'September-2013'
GROUP BY balance_type
```

But it will SUM all balance_month.

Any advice?

Comment: Is there several `balance_type` values in the specified data range? Probably, but, could you provide some data between 'August-2013'  and 'September-2013' just to check ?

Comment: What is the data type of the `balance_month` column?

Comment: I set varchar type for balance_month

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a string column for balance_month. `BETWEEN August-2013 and September-2013` is basically `BETWEEN A AND S` in the alphabet (don't know how to describe it better, lacking english skills here). J for January and F for February is between A and S, so MySQL counts those in. Convert your column to a date

```
WHERE ... AND STR_TO_DATE(balance_month, '%M-%Y') BETWEEN '2013-08-01' 
  and '2013-09-30'
```

But, if I were you I'd get rid of the column and use a real date column. Otherwise an index can not be used on it, when you always have to use a function like str_to_date() on it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work...

```
SELECT balance_type AS balance_type, SUM(balance_amount) AS value_sum
FROM t_balance 
WHERE badge_id = '110702' && STR_TO_DATE(balance_month,'%M-%Y') BETWEEN '2013-08-01' 
  and '2013-09-30'
GROUP BY balance_type
```

Answer (score 0):

By an unfortunate twist of fate, all months *are* between `August-2013` and `September-2013` -- as you are probably comparing on *strings* not *date*.

On MySQL, proper date have the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) (or one derivable) type and should be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.